# How to use FOREACH .. GENERATE statement to transform my data with PIG?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I have some data like this:

```
 ({(A),(A),(A)},{(B),(F),(D)},{(2),(2),(1)})
 ({(B),(B),(B)},{(A),(F),(C)},{(2),(1),(1)})
 ({(C),(C),(C)},{(F),(A),(B)},{(2),(1),(1)})
```

I would like to use FOREACH statement and generate this:

```
 (A,B,2,F,2,D,1)
 (B,A,2,F,1,C,1)
```

Please a code example will be great

Answer (score 0):

FLATTEN will break out the individual tuples and then you can do a group